# Get question from specified user/area?

Tags: discussion, support

Can I filter questions to a specific country/user, (For example: Egypt, UAE..)?

Comment: In short... no. (well, you can view posts by a specific user - but you can't  (using any builtin way) view posts by criteria such as location)

Comment: No, but you can use https://data.stackexchange.com/ to filter questions by  specific country/user

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson: One problem is that location is a free text field. It's impossible to reliably get the user's real location from that.

Comment: Can you clarify why that would be useful for Stack Overflow site? I can't see any *practical* reason for doing so... (Also "was latest assignment from my school already posted and answered" may be one :) )

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You're completely right, in fact I tried to do that, just to know and measure (not sure) how developer thinks in some areas!, and also to measure the quality of question in this area, this was my reason. Strange I know :^^

Answer (score 10):

No, this is not possible.

As was pointed out by Cerbrus in his [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364129/812149), you can look at the location that people filled in on their profile. As was pointed out by  "I am the Most Stupid Person" in their [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364128/get-question-from-specified-user-area#comment562345_364128), you can even use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer to filter on that field. But it relies on people honestly entering that field. Many have not entered it all, or entered nonsensical values - or just entered "Earth" or something like that.

The reason that you can't filter on location, is that we don't care where questions or answers come from. What matters is if a question is good, if it fits our quality guidelines.

We judge posts by the content, not by the person or the location.

Answer (score 6):

Nope. There is no such filter available on the site.

You could visit a user's *profile* to look at all of their questions / answers, but that's it.
It's not possible to search by location.